# Splitting a CSV File by value of specific column

Tags: csv, split, arcgis

I have multiple CSV files that I need to split into 67 separate files each. Each sheet has over a million rows and dozens of columns. One of the columns is called "Code" and it ranges from 1 to 67 which is what I have to base the split on. I have been doing this split manually by selecting all of the rows within each value (1, 2, 3, etc) and pasting them into their own CSV file and saving them, but this is taking way too long. I usually use ArcGIS to create some kind of batch file split, but I am not having much luck in doing so this go around. Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to awk there's a good way to do this.

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
Code,a,b,c
1,x,x,x
2,x,x,x
3,x,x,x
```

You want a command like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 {print $0 >> "code" $1 ".csv"}' data.csv
```

That will save it to files like `code1.csv` etc., skipping the header line.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to tweak that command so it can run in VBA?